# Neo4j Cypher recursive query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query that returns a `TagSynonym` node between two `Tag` nodes:

```
MATCH (t:Tag)<-[:FOR]-(ts:TagSynonym)-[:HAS]->(s:Tag) 
WHERE t.id = {tagId} AND s.id = {synonymId} 
RETURN ts
```

Additionally, the `s:Tag` node itself can have its own `TagSynonym` nodes like:

```
(s)<-[:FOR]-(ts:TagSynonym)-[:HAS]->(ss:Tag)
```

and `ss` can have its own `TagSynonym` and so on and so forth.

The depth of this structure can be pretty big.

Please help me to extend this query in order to return all `TagSynonym` established on `t:Tag` and all of its synonym successors(tags for `s:Tag` and deeper up to the end of this recursive structure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this look like it is going in the right direction?

Basically use `apoc.path.expandConfig` to start at `s` and start grabbing new `TagSynonym` and `Tag` nodes.

```
MATCH (t:Tag)<-[:FOR]-(ts:TagSynonym)-[:HAS]->(s:Tag) 
WHERE t.id = {tagId} AND s.id = {synonymId} 
WITH t, ts, s
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(s
{
  uniqueness:"NODE_GLOBAL",
  labelFilter:"TagSynonym|Tag",
  relationshipFilter: '<FOR|HAS>'
}) YIELD path
RETURN t, ts, s, path
```

Optionally, to achieve something similar without using the APOC library you could consider something along the lines of this query...

```
MATCH (t:Tag)<-[:FOR]-(ts:TagSynonym)-[:HAS]->(s:Tag) 
WHERE t.id = {tagId} AND s.id = {synonymId} 
WITH t,ts,s
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(s)-[:FOR|HAS*]-(end:Tag)
WHERE NOT (end)<-[:FOR]-()
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I apologize but is it possible to implement without apoc? I tried to install apoc previously but failed(especially for my tests based on the embedded Neo4j) and use a pure Cypher queries at my application.

Comment: I added a non-APOC query that might work out for you.  I am not sure how it will behave with your data.  Also be wary of the bare `*` in the path expansion; it could quickly get out of control depending on how intricately related your `Tag` and `TagSynonym` nodes.